# htaccess redirect from http to https + GET param

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to edit my .httaccess configuration. I want redirect everythink to https, but if I try this, what I found on stackoverflow:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It wont redirect.

Now my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore all existing files and directories for rewriting     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\d+^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w+^/]*)$ /index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Rewrite rules like:

```
^([\d+^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

working well if I want

- www.mydomain.com/523

it is like

- www.mydomain.com/index.php?id=523

So how can I append my code to redirect from 
http:// to https:// and my older rewrite rules will still work?

Answer (score 0):

Try  :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI [NE,L,R]
  # ignore all existing files and directories for rewriting     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([\d+^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w+^/]*)$ /index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: it doesn't work. If i write url www.mydomain.com nothink happens and it cleared url input on browser (without any error or redirect)

Comment: @Michal what exactly happens when you type the url? I have tested these rules on my server and it works.

Comment: I type in browser my url, hit enter and then browser clears url input and nothink happens (i still see my default browser page with bookmarks)

Comment: Now I see in third line misstake (ending }) If I corrected it now and I clear cache, my browser writes, that this page has too many redirects

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this for GET params:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore all existing files and directories for rewriting     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\d+^/]*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w+^/]*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I can't solve it for homepage and all other pages. I'm using JS location.replace instead. If someone will know how to set .htaccess to do these things synchronous:

- redirect every files into https
- and all digits and words after slash on homepage (example.com/63) redirect to https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?id=$1 (as GET param)